# How to draw reflection of ImageView?

Tags: android, image, coverflow

I  have a coverflow widget  [link](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/12/android-reflections-with-bitmaps.html)  in my android application.I am using customized imageview, having border and some texts over images, inside the coverflow widget.

I want to show the reflection of the **imageview instead of image** .How is it possible.?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this and modify as your need.
[link](http://tomtheguvnor.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/creating-a-reusable-fading-reflection-view-effect-in-android/)