# android-GAMA Carousel Component

Tags: android, imageview

I want to use `Carousel` widget ([GAMA Carousel Component](http://developer.digitalaria.com/devguide/gama/en/gama/carousel_android.php)) in my app. I need to add reflection effect to my images which are being shown via `Carousel`. does any one know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For example you can do it like described here: http://tomtheguvnor.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/creating-a-reusable-fading-reflection-view-effect-in-android/ (got this link from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12778942/1643188)